# How deep down the DOM tree is contenteditable-ity retained?

Tags: dom, contenteditable

#### **Background:**

I wish to execute work based off whether a node is content editable or not. The node is captured `onkeyup` through `event.target`. Consider this complex contenteditable node structure:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <div contenteditable="true">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <a href="google.com">
                    <span style="color: red;">Hi!</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ol>
         "A text node"
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish a `keyup` inside the `span` node, as well as the text node, to detect them as a contenteditable node and perform work.

So, I wrote this function (long but straightforward):

```
// callForParent: flag to prevent infinite recursion
window.isContentEditable = function(node, callForParent){
    var tgN = node && node.tagName,
        attr, parentCount, parent, MAX_PARENTS_CHECKED = INTEGER_VALUE (3,4,5,etc.);

    // insanity checks first
    if(!node || tgN === "TEXTAREA" || tgN === "INPUT" || !node.getAttribute)
        return false;
    else{
        attr = node.attr("contenteditable");

        // empty string to support <element contenteditable> markup
        if(attr === "" || attr === "true" || attr === "plaintext-only")
            return true;

        // avoid infinite recursion
        if(callForParent) return false;

        parentCount = 1;
        parent = node;

        do{
            parent = parent.parentNode;
            parentCount++;

            if(!parent) return false;
            // parent check call
            if(isContentEditable(parent, true)) return true;
        }while(parentCount <= MAX_PARENTS_CHECKED);

        return false;
    }
};
```

#### Problem:

Notice the counter limit `MAX_PARENTS_CHECKED` above. That makes sure how many levels up the DOM tree I go in search of a parent contenteditable node.

Does that counter affect the logical correctness of my program? I mean, like in the HTML structure I showed above, we need the limit to be `4` to cover all cases. There might be need of more.

> But I fear that increasing the limit greater than some point might make non-contenteditable nodes to be detected to be detected as contenteditable. Is this fear of mine true/possible? **Are there examples to show that deep descendants of contenteditable node can be non-CE node?**

I don't want to execute things in a deep-down non-CE node if say, it CANNOT be edited by the user and then my app gives an error.

<sup>Sorry if I sound nitpicky but I need confirmation</sup>

**UPDATE:** As confirmed by user3297291 in the comments, there exist instances where `keyup` on a non-CE child of a CE node are detected as having `event.target` == to the parent and NOT the child, contrary to what one might expect. These are situations where my app might fire, and expect a caret `Range`, `Selection`, etc. to perform some work, and there it will give an error.

> Does there exist some fix/proper way of doing this?

Comment: No, that’s not a thing, and I’m not sure why you have a limit. Keep going until you hit `document`.

Comment: @Ryan Yes I was only making sure. Please make it an answer for me to accept. Also, if you can link to some specs/etc. that'd be good.

Comment: I had a go at trying to spot potential issues (thinking the code could get a bit more concise...) and couldn't really see a problem with traversing the DOM... The only issue I *did* run into is that when you click a `contenteditable="false"` element *inside* an editable element, the `keyup` `event.target` is the editable element... (https://jsfiddle.net/orhLju99/ click last `<p>` and type -> console logs `true`)

Comment: @user3297291 Yep, that's a good catch! Thanks! The fix should be to check if the `content-editable` attribute _is set to `false`_. Should that be sufficient?

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but it doesn't work since the `keyup` event isn't triggered for those elements...

Comment: @user3297291 Yes, you're right.